# How to program an equation with factorials

Tags: java

I need help programing this equation using java

```
c(n)=((2n-3)!) / ( (n!)*((n+1)!+5) )
```

This is what I have and it gives me 0

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: make a separate method to calculate factorial and use it in your equation.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori This is then more likely to exceed some upper bound of int or long capacity.

Comment: Are you familiar with recursion yet?  This is the perfect example to write a simple recursive function with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the nth Catalan number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539844/calculate-the-nth-catalan-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less likely to exceed some integer/long max value (and uses requires less cycles):

```
public static long d(int n){
    long top = 1;
    long bom = n + 1;
    for(int q = 1; q <= n; q++){
        top *= n + q; 
        bom *= q;
    }
    return top/bom;
}
```

Comment: If the overflow becomes a real issue, one could possibly cast to `double`, use logarithms for all the operations (better precision), exponentiate, and then round to the nearest integer. Not sure how likely it is to get the wrong answer though (due to floating-point imprecisions). Thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to say? My comment has nothing to do with Stirling's approximation. I meant that instead of doing `(a*b)/(c*d)`, one can do `log(a)+log(b)-log(c)-log(d)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
top=2*q*top;
```

should be

```
top=2*q*(2*q - 1)*top;
```

as otherwise `top` omits the odd factors (but I agree with the comment that you should factor out a factorial function).